Using Residue Theorem for functions with removable singularities
So for an Integral of the form $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ixa} -1}{x(x^2 + 1)} dx$. My intuition is to use complex contour integration and use a contour that is a semi-circle on the upper-half plane and avoids the pole at $x = 0$ (principal value). My question is, if I instead define the function $f(x) = \frac{e^{ixa} -1}{x}$ then since this function is analytic everywhere since there is a removable singularity at x = 0. would it just suffice to only consider the pole at $x = i$ re-defining the integral as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{(x^2 + 1)} dx$ where $f(x)$ would be considered analytic everywhere and I don't have to deform my contour to avoid the pole at $x= 0$. So I am essentially only using the reside at $x = i$ to compute the value of my integral

Yes, that's correct  :)  Alternatively you can consider the residue at $z=0$ as well, but that residue will equal $0$.

So also for f(x) to be analytic all of its derivatives at x=0 must be defined, I checked for the first derivative and at x = 0 f(x) goes to -a^2/2. Is it safe to conclude that then it will be defined for all its derivatives wrt to x. Also I am not sure you can consider the residue at z=0, since I am integrating along the real axis and would like to avoid the real pole at z=0, in this case instead of using residues wouldnt you use an infinitesimal semi-circle that avoids the pole at z=0. Sorry for all the questions, I appreciate the help!

^^So the question is whether or not including this infinitesimal semicircle around the pole at z=0 would give the same answer as not including it. Just added an additional comment to make the question more clear!

By the fact that the series of $e^{p x}-1$ starts with $p x$, there is no singularity at $z=0 $ and you can use any contour passing the pole pair $z=\pm i.$

There is no pole at 0. A removable singularity is not a pole.

You may prove that $(e^{iaz}-1)/z$ is analytic by observing its Taylor series.
